# Taking list of mp4 URLs and downloading file python

Tags: python, download, mp4

How would I go about navigating to a URL that's stored in a list and downloading the file? I'd preferably like to be able to store the MP4 file as it's clip title. I've used requests to retrieve the urls.

Thanks

```
list_clips = ['https://clips.twitch.tv/SpeedySneakyHeronKappaClaus', 'https://clips.twitch.tv/SplendidGiantPuffinThunBeast', 'https://clips.twitch.tv/ArtsyAuspiciousHamburgerThisIsSparta', 'https://clips.twitch.tv/BoringNiceHerbsSaltBae']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's requests module to download the file. Please refer the code below

```py
import requests, os

for clips in list_clips:
    clip_title = os.path.basename(clips)
    r = requests.get(clips)
    with open(clip_title+'.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```